# Array of generic type with different parameters in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Let's say we have a generic `interface`

```
interface CompareOp<T>{
  a: T;
  b: T;
  cmp: (v1: T, v2: T) => number;
}
```

I'm looking for a way to create a type for an array of `CompareOp` of any type. For example:

```
// valid, each compare function receives the type of its fields
[
  {a: 1, b:1, cmp: (v1: number, v2: number) => v1 - v2},
  {a: 'a', b: 'b', cmp: (v1: string, v2: string) => v1.localCompare(v2)}
]
// invalid, compare function does not match fields
[
  {a: 1, b:1, cmp: (v1: string, v2: string) => v1.localCompare(v2),
  {a: 'a', b: 'b', cmp: (v1: number, v2: number) => v1 - v2}
]
```

Is there a way to express the type of this array in TypeScript?

Comment: Could  you provide an example of which result you're waiting for ? Would you like the second array to be considered as an array of CompareOp ? 
The issue happening in your second array is that the type used in your operation does not satisfy the generic declaration of your interface: If a & b are of type T, so should be the ones used in your cmp as well. 
If you want them to possibly be different, then your interface should be CompareOp<T, U>{ a: T; b: T; cmp: (v1: U, v2: U) => number; }. Is that what you're searchinng for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a stand-alone type that performs individual validation of array elements.

What you *can* do is to utilize the *inference* of a generic function and use a *reverse mapped type* to validate each array element against `CompareOp`.

```
interface CompareOp<T> {
  a: T;
  b: T;
  cmp: (v1: T, v2: T) => number;
}

function compareOp<T extends any[]>(
  arr: [...{ [K in keyof T]: CompareOp<T[K]> }]
) {}

compareOp([
  { a: 1, b: 1, cmp: (v1: number, v2: number) => v1 - v2 },
  { a: "a", b: "b", cmp: (v1: string, v2: string) => v1.localeCompare(v2) },
]);

compareOp([
  { a: 1, b: 1, cmp: (v1: string, v2: string) => v1.localeCompare(v2) },
//              ~~~ Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
  { a: "a", b: "b", cmp: (v1: number, v2: number) => v1 - v2 },
//                  ~~~ Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
]);
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsC2AHOUIDy2APACoB8yA3gFDLJwBcypA3HcgEbNscI7MAFADcAjDwA0yYQCYeASmQBeSiACumTtHYBfGjRhqQCMMHQhkCLLnxEyyCAA9IIACYBnBiACeAbQC65IIceFDMvgB0UVTIvgDSyKDIANYQ3ugwLP7MGDh4hCSk8YHIOv40ilR6NFZ5ttiCvhwxTMiiUtxtUvzYQmLM6prQUrIDGlpQiirSosgAtNIypRLNDMwARHDrHRuc25YCyCLiyO5gUKAA5iNyp+dXU5RiEQA26AhwLxC5NhAiMoodCt-PJ2DVrPkiI1Vq12lxmHCen0TmcLiBrotmKiHsonqJXu9Pt8Ifh-oCVvQWhstjtkOs9t1DscxkMoDcWRNHjN5otljQQewgA)

Comment: What does the spread opreator do there?

Comment: The compiler will infer `T` as an array type if we don't use a variadic tuple here. But we need a tuple type for `T` so that each element in the array gets its own type element in `T`

Comment: This seems exactly like what i need!, But cant seem to find anything regarding the term "reverse mapped type" online, could you exaplain how it works or link something?

Comment: @Plargato - I have seen no official documentation which uses the term "reverse mapped type". I have seen it mostly used by TypeScript-contributors and in the source code of the compiler itself.